# Why was only the light hidden at creation?

Tags: creation, lighting, tractate-chagiga

In Bereshis 1:3-4 God creates light and differentiates between light and dark. Chazal in Hagigah 12a each us that God saw the original light was not appropriate for the wicked to use and hid it away for the righteous in the future.

My question is why was this the only thing in creation that God felt needed to be hidden away from the wicked?

Comment: Who's to say that other things weren't hidden away as well? The Mishna lists ten things that were created at the beginning but were only revealed later: the mouth of Bilaam's donkey, the well of Miriam, the staff of Aharon, etc.

Comment: Presumably this was some metaphysical creation; light which does not emanate from the sun. It appears that the wicked are only granted access to physical creation.